# Measuring the effectiveness of a pattern recognition software

Tags: pattern-recognition

Are there any objective methods of assessment or standardized tests available to measure the effectiveness of a software that does pattern recognition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are many methods.  You would need to specify which model you're using, because it can vary.

For instance, Some models will be compared based on the [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) or [BIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) criteria.  In other cases, one would look at the [MSE from cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) (as, for instance, with a support vector machine).

1. I recommend reading [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/) by Christopher Bishop.
2. This is also discussed in Chapter 5 on Credibility, and particularly section 5.5 "Comparing data mining methods" of [Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120884070) by Witten and Frank (which discusses Weka in detail).
3. Lastly, you should also have a look at [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman which is available for free online.